# Hide/Remove an option value from select if a value is selected/changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to hide or remove the `<option value=" "></option>` when some value is selected from another drop down.

So this is something how I need it:

```
<Select id="first">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

Now, when a option `two` is selected, the below drop down's first value which is a blank string `""` should either get `remove` or `hide` from the selection.

```
<select id="too">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="time"time</option>
</select>
```

JQuery is a very effective library and I am still getting into it as a begineer. Any help on how to do this would be a great help

Comment: please add the jQuery you have tried so far. Your question may be clearer if you add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( "#first" ).change(function() {
    if(2 == $(this).val()){
        $("#too").children()[0].remove();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NHM28/

Comment: Thank you Joris, I have learned if I mention the script function with `window onload` it will also prevent the state of functioning even if we refresh the page? please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes - see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution  plain javascript

```
<html>
<Select id="firstSelect">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
</select>


<select id="secondSelect">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="time">time</option>
</select>

<script>
    var node = document.getElementById("firstSelect");
    node.addEventListener('change', removeOptionTag);

    function removeOptionTag(){
        var secNode = document.getElementById('secondSelect');
        var allTags = secNode.getElementsByTagName('option');
        secNode.removeChild(allTags[0]);
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of doing it.
HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").click(function(){
        if($("select option:selected").val() != ""){
            $("select option[value='']").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9w6cN/